# Partitioning a cone into sub cones

Tags: linear-algebra

Say $T=\{\mathbf x^i,\dots,\mathbf x^n\}$ with $\mathbf x^i=(x^i_1,x^i_2)\in\Bbb R^2_+$, assume that $x^i_1\ne x^{i'}_1$ and let their indices be ordered so that $i> i'\implies x^i_1>x^{i'}_1$. Consider the cone spanned by $T$. This cone can be partitioned into $n-1$ disjoint sub cones each of them spanned by $\mathbf x^i$ and $\mathbf x^{i+1}$.

I'd like to achieve the same partitioning in higher dimensions. In $\Bbb R^m$ the minimum sub cone of interest to me would be spanned by $m$ points. I imagine that there are $n \choose m$ potential sub cones, but, of course, there's lots of overlapping (as would have happenned had we considered the $n\choose 2$ possible subcones in $T$). In $\Bbb R^2$ this is dealt with by the assumption of the points being ordered. But I don't know how to do it in higher dimensions.

To make things worse, I'm only interested in the partitions that are "visible" from the origin. Imagine we had $n=4$ in $\Bbb R^3_+$: the points would define a pyramid and looking at it from the origin at least one of its faces would not be visible.  I'd be interested in determining the number of faces visible from the origin and identifying the points that span the corresponding sub cone.

I'm hoping that should this be feasible in $\Bbb R^3$ it will be "easily" generalizable to $m>3$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area of active research that might be answered best if you posted it on Math Overflow. You can do a web search on decomposition of cones into *simplicial sub cones* and probably pull up a large number of references. (You can think of this as a sort of triangulation problem.)  The special case in which the vertices have rational or integer coordinates is of particular interest in combinatorics, because the simplicial decomposition simplifies the problem of counting the number of lattice points inside the cone. Here are links to an overview of such applications that might acquaint you with some useful terminology. This just scratches the surface.

[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/researchsummary/barvinokalgorithm-latte1.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Edeloera/researchsummary/barvinokalgorithm-latte1.pdf)

https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/NormalizOS.pdf